# Website gallery section strips on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello i'm making a website layout and i'm having a problem with responsivnes. 
On bigger screen it looks like this[image]

While on smaller one i get this [image]

Gallery strips not in one row but in two
Here's my HTML file

```css
body header
    {
         font: 400 100px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #menu ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #menu li{
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        margin-right: 1px;
    }
        
    #menu li a{
        display: block;
        min-width: 140px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-family:
            "Helvetica Neue"
            ,Helvetica,
            Arial,
            sans-serif;
        
        color: #fff;
        background: #2f3036;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /*hover for top level 
    
    #menu li:hover a {
        background: #19c589;
    }
    
    
    /*drop down links
    
    #menu li:hover ul a{
        background: #f3f3f3;
        color: #2f3036;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
    
    /*drop down hover
    
    #menu li:hover ul a:hover{
        background: #19c589;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    /*hide drop down links
    
    #menu li ul{
        display: none;
        float: none;
        
    }
    /*vertical drop down
    #menu li ul li{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    /*prevent text wrapping
    #menu li ul li a{
        width:auto;
        min-width: 100px;
        padding:0 20px;
    }
    /*Display drop down on hover
    #menu ul li a:hover + .hidden,.hidden:hover{
        display: block;
    }
    */
    /*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.75em;
        
        color:#777;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        
    }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
    {
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #777;
    }
     
    h2
    {
        letter-spacing: -0.025em;
    }
     
    h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a
    {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    #header{
        height:250px;
        position: relative;
        background: url(horizons.jpg);
        background-position-x: 30%;
        background-position-y: 90%;
        background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
        /*
        background-attachment: fixed
        */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    #menuDiv ul {
        position: relative;
        width:auto;
     list-style-type:none;
     margin:0;
        margin-top: 10px;
     padding:0;
        top:0;
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      
    }
    
    /*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
    #menuDiv li {
     display:inline-block;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 1px;
      
    
    }
    
    /*Style for menu links*/
    #menuDiv  li a {
     display:block;
     min-width:140px;
     height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 
     font-family: "Oleo Script","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     color: #fff;
     background: #2f3036;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /*Hover state for top level links*/
     #menuDiv li:hover a {
     background: #19c589;
    }
    
    /*Style for dropdown links*/
     #menuDiv li:hover ul a {
     background: #f3f3f3;
     color: #2f0404;
      
        
     height: 50px;
     line-height: 40px;
    }
    
    /*Hover state for dropdown links*/
    #menuDiv  li:hover ul a:hover {
     background: #19c589;
     color: #fff;
    }
    
    /*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
     #menuDiv  li ul {
     display: none;
    }
    
    /*Make dropdown links vertical*/
    #menuDiv li ul li {
     display: block;
     float: none;
    }
    
    /*Prevent text wrapping*/
    #menuDiv  li ul li a {
     width: inherit;
     min-width: 100px;
     padding: 0 20px;
    }
    
    /*Display the dropdown on hover*/
    #menuDiv  ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
     display: block;
    }
    #menuDiv ul#menu li:hover .hidden{  
        display: block;
    }
    
    /*For smartphone devices*/
    
    @media screen and(max-width : 760px){
        /*Dropdow inline*/
     #nav   ul{
            position:static;
            display: none;
        }
        /*vertical spacing*/
      #nav  li{
            margin-bottom: 1px;
        }
        /*Make all menu links full width*/
     #nav   ul li, li a{
            width: 100%;
        }
        /*Display 'show menu' link*/
      #nav .show-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    /*Show menu for phone browsers and hide it by default*/
    #nav .show-menu{
        font-family: "Helvectica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background: #19c589;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 0;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Hide checkbox*/
    #nav input[type=checkbox]{
        display: none;
    }
    
    
    /*Show menu when checkbox is chechked*/
    #nav input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
        display: block;
    }
    /*Wrap of the article
    setting some positon width etc
    */
    */
    
     #articleWrap{
       
    }
    #allContent{
        vertical-align: baseline;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }
    
    #articleContent{
       max-width: 50%;
        font-size: 11pt;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        max-width:500px;
        min-width: 100px;
    }
    /*leftSidebar holds row of links and comment section*/
    
    
    /*row holds article field and leftSidebar*/
    /*
    .row {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top:50px;
       
        
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float:left;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        top:0;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
    .row header{
        font-size:3.3em;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 40px;
         
    }
    
    .row list1{
        float:left;
    }
    .row list2{
        clear:left
    }
    .leftList{
        float:left;
    }
    .leftList ul{
       
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .leftList li{
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 2px;
    }
    .leftList li:hover{
        transform: scale(1.05);
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    leftSideBar properties*/
    
    
    section,#textWrap {
        margin-bottom: 3em;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    section {
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        
    }
    /*Header element in section*/
    #mainContent header{
        /* padding-left: 50px; */
        padding-top:40px;
        margin-top:10px;
        font-size:3.0em;
        line-height: 1.3em;
        letter-spacing: 2.7px;
        text-align: center;
        
        
    }
    
    /*Left side bar configuration*/
    
    /*date of comment add */
    .posted 
    {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .sidebar:first-child>*{
        padding-top:0!important;
    }
    .sidebar>*{
        padding-left:50px;
        min-width: 400px;
    }
    .sidebar .row header{
        padding-top:40px;
        font-size:26pt;
    }
    /**/
    /* remove bullets from lists */
    .article-list li{
         list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    
    .article-list a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#b9ba9b;
        padding-left: 10px;
    
    }
    .article-list a:hover{
        color:#6f6f5d;
        
    }
    .leftList header {
       
       
       
    }
    .commentSection header{
        font-size:26pt;
    }
    */
    
        
    }
    
    #textWrap{
        width: 80.0%;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    #text{
        font-size:13pt;
        
    
    }
    #mainContent{
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 1000px;
        min-width: 300px;
        
    }
    #main{
        width: 100%;
    }
    #galleryIn{
    
       
    }
    
    .imageIn img{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        margin:10px;
        float:left;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        
       
    }
    
    
    .article-list li
    {
    
    }
    
    
    
    /*Images preview */
    
    
    #separatorImage header{
        font-size:26pt;
    }
    
    
    
    ul.defaul li{
        font-size:0.95em;
    }
```

```html
<html >
    <head>
    <meta lang="pl">
    <META charset="UTF-8">
    <TITLE>Tytuł strony!</TITLE>
        
        
        
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700,500,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <META NAME="description" CONTENT="Site description">
    <META NAME="robots" CONTENT="ALL">
     
    </head>
    <body>
       
        
             <div id="header">
           
            
            </div>
        <div id="SelectNoStyle">
               <div id="menuDiv">
      <ul id="menu">
      <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">About ￬</a>
       <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Gallery ￬</a>
       <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ConceptArt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Funny</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
       
                    
    
        
       <div id="allContent">
       
             
         
               
        
            <div id="mainContent">    
            <div id="textWrap">
                <section id="text">
                    <header style="font-size:3.4em;">Do you live fully ?</header>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor.
                    </p>
                    <p>    
                    Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.
                    varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    varius in, purus. Integer ultrices posuere cubilia Curae, Nulla ipsum dolor lacus, suscipit adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ultrices volutpat. Nullam wisi ultricies a, gravida vitae, dapibus risus ante sodales lectus blandit eu, tempor diam pede cursus vitae, ultricies eu, faucibus quis, porttitor eros cursus lectus, pellentesque eget, bibendum a, gravida ullamcorper quam. Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus. Sed vel lectus. Ut sagittis, ipsum dolor quam.
                    </p>
    
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
           <div class="sidebar">
             <div class="row">
                
                
                    
            <div id="separatorImage">
            <header> New in gallery </header>
            <div id="galleryIn">
                
                <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                 <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imageIn">
                <a href="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg">
                <img src="images/landscapes/839274-landscape-sunset.jpg"></a>
                </div>
    
    
    
    
             </div>
        
        </div>
          
                    
           <div class="commentSection">
           <section class="leftComment">
                        <header> Last&nbsp;Comments</header>
                        <ul class="last-com-list"></ul>
                            <li>
                                <p class="posted">
                                     MAY 21, 2014 | (10 ) COMMENTS
                                </p>
                                <p class="comment">
                                 Nullam non wisi a sem eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. Pellentesque viverra enim.
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        
                            <li>
                                <p class="posted">
                                    MAY 21, 2014 | (10 ) COMMENTS
                                </p>
                                <p class="comment">
                                Nullam non wisi a sem eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. Pellentesque viverra enim.
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            
               
             </section>
            </div>
           </div>
                    
                    
        
    
        
    
    
    
    
        <!--PHP gallery which loads images from folder   -->
    
            
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you please give me the online link ?

Comment: which problem exactly?

Comment: The "new in gallery" text stays on right side in some screen widths, and the gallery section should move to bottom and in each row there should be equal number of images